# Game Center: ensure badge shows for app in iTunes

Tags: app-store, game-center

How do I ensure that iTunes shows the Game Center badge for an app, like so:

[image: GC badge]
<sub>(source: [justanotheripadblog.com](http://justanotheripadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/GameCenterBadge.jpg))</sub>

Do you have to set any special flag in the app's plist, etc?  Or does correctly enabling Game Center automatically mean the badge will show in iTunes (when approved)?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your app has a match with the local player as the one to move, you will be badged.